# Disable Dynamic Brightness Dell LCD

Tags: dell, brightness

I have a Dell Inspiron 11 3000 Series laptop that has built in Dynamic Contrast/Brightness in the screen. The screen automatically adjusts it's brightness according to how many white pixels are on the screen.

In windows Dell has a "Quickset" utility that I download and is able to disable this Power Saving Feature, however "Quickset" is unavailable for linux and running it in wine hasn't proven fruitful. Anyone know how to disable Dell Dynamic Brightness in Ubuntu?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe `dconf-editor` could help you. I found in it an option that could rule the behavior of auto-brightness:

[image]

If you want to try, you can check if this option is enable or not installing `dconf-editor`.

So run this command:

```
sudo apt-get install dconf-editor
```

to install it. Now open `dconf-editor` and navigate to

```
com.ubuntu.system
```

Here you can see the `auto-brightness` option.

I hope this could help you.

Comment: I tried dconf write /com/ubuntu/touch/system/auto-brightness false and successfully created the key, but it had no effect. Auto-brightness still active. Maybe it is a bios setting?

Comment: Another feedback: I tried all bios menus and options and found nothing related to auto-brightness. Only an option to set default brightness in AC mode and in battery mode. My PC is a Dell XPS 13.

Comment: Update: it seems to be an issue related to the screen firmware. Dell has released an update intended to fix this. As I have Linux only here, I was unable to test it.  Here's the link: http://www.dell.com/support/home/br/pt/brbsdt1/Drivers/DriversDetails?driverId=59XRT&fileId=3645713989&osCode=WT64A&productCode=xps-13-9365-2-in-1-laptop&languageCode=bp&categoryId=AP

Comment: I also have this issue on dell xps 9300 running ubuntu 20.04